# Reactjs map nested array to load image urls in <img> tag

Tags: reactjs

I have this in my state

```
theatre: [
  {
    "naslov": "Dear Elena Sergeevna",
    "id": "t00",
    "godina": "2015.",
    "naslovnaSlika": "http://xx.com/content/djs_prez.png",
    "naslovKlasa": "sergeevna_naslov",
    "nazivGalerije": ["http://xx.com/content/skulpture/skp4.jpg", "http://xx.com/content/skulpture/skp3.jpg", "http://xx.com/content/skulpture/skp5.jpg", "http://xx.com/content/skulpture/skp0.jpg"],
    "slikaKlasa": "sergeevna"
  }, {
    "naslov": "Osecaj brade",
    "id": "t01",
    "godina": "2017.",
    "naslovnaSlika": "http://x.com/content/Osecaj-brade_prez.png",
    "naslovKlasa": "osecajbrade_naslov",
    "nazivGalerije": [{"1":"http://xx.com/content/skulpture/skp4.jpg"}, {"2":"http://xx.com/content/skulpture/skp3.jpg"}, {"3":"http://xx.com/content/skulpture/skp5.jpg"}, {"4":"http://xx.com/content/skulpture/skp0.jpg"}],
    "slikaKlasa": "osecajbrade"
  }
]
```

I am getting a single object through an event listener and when i print it out I get the whole object. 
I would like to use the links from "nazivGalerije" and to make a loop that prints out images.

This is what I'm trying but it isn't working

```
const ContainerTheatre = (props) => {
  return (
      <div className={props.klasa.join(' ')}>
        <div className="text_segment">
        console.log{props.selectedTheatre.nazivGalerije}
        <p>{props.selectedTheatre.naslov}</p>
        {props.selectedTheatre.nazivGalerije.map(slika => {
          return <ImageLoop
                    url={slika} />
                  })}
        </div>
        <img onClick={props.zatvori} src="http://xx.com/content/close_w.png" alt="close" className="close-popup" />
      </div>
  )
}
```

the "selectedTheatre" is the single object that I pass to know the one that is clicked on.
what I want is to pass all links from the array to another component via this

```
{props.selectedTheatre.nazivGalerije.map(slika => {
              return <ImageLoop
                        url={slika} />
                      })}
```

it may be the worst possible approach so thanks for all the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do conditional check for nested objects before accessing them like below

And also you need to set unique key to ImageLoop element inside map like below otherwise you will always get last element

Change

```
  {props.selectedTheatre.nazivGalerije.map(slika => {
          return <ImageLoop
                    url={slika} />
                  })}
```

To

```
 {props.selectedTheatre && props.selectedTheatre.nazivGalerije && props.selectedTheatre.nazivGalerije.map((slika, index)=> {
          return <ImageLoop Key={'Key-'+index} url={slika} />
  })}
```

Comment: Someday we will have our [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) and you can re-write it as `props?.selectedTheatre?.nazivGalerije?.map(...)`

Comment: Yes but that is possible only in Type script. Isn’t it?

Comment: @HemadriDasari "_TypeScript unfortunately does not yet support an optional chaining operator. While there is longstanding community interest, TypeScript is waiting for clarity from TC39 on the direction JavaScript will ultimately take with respect to optional chaining support._"  You can check [here](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-optional-chaining/) to see the current status.